# Nested Owned Type Contains Navigation Property - Not Work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I try to define my data model much closer to domain models, but I think that Ef does not support this simple need. I worked with ownsMany, ownsOne, hasMany, hasOne, withOwner, Navigation builder, IEntityTypeConfiguration, and ... in different ways.

```
public class Custom
{
    [Required]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Demo demo{ get; set; }
}

[Owned()]
public class Demo  
{
    public virtual ICollection<PDemo> pDemoes{ get; set; }
}

public class PDemo
{
    [Required]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Custom")]
    public int CustomId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Custom Custom{ get; set; }
}

public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Custom> custom { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PDemo> pDemoes{ get; set; }
        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
```

EF Core Add-Migration Says :

```
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Demo.pDemoes' of type 'ICollection<PDemo>'.
Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or 
by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Comment: What does the db side look like?

Comment: 2 tables named custom and PDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to find the best answer, so raise an issue on the official GitHub repository for Entity framework Core  :
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore
and find out that the error message is not appropriate, and the development team adds this feature in the next sprints backlog.

issue link :
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27175